# Android Kotlin Retrofit MVVM return Null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-mvvm

I'm currently making a sample project about diagrams. I'm starting to use MVVM architecture recently, and I got stuck when the response is null. I also checked the Mutable Live Data to make sure that it is calling the API. Here's some of my code and the error-tag:

**Model.kt**

```
data class Model(
    @SerializedName("FID") val FID: Int,
    @SerializedName("region") val region: String,
    @SerializedName("positive") val positive: Float
) {
}
```

**ModelWrap.kt**

```
data class ModelWrap(@SerializedName("samplesAPI") val attributes: Model){
}
```

**ApiClient.kt**

```
object ApiClient {
    var retrofitService: ApiInterface? = null
    const val BASE_URL = "https://sampleapi.../"

    fun getApiSample() : ApiInterface {
        if (retrofitService == null){
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
            retrofitService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
        return retrofitService!!
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface.kt**

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("samples")
    fun getSampleData(): Call<List<ModelWrap>>
}
```

**MainViewModel.kt**

```
class MainViewModelconstructor(private val repository: ModelRepository) : ViewModel(){
    val sampleList= MutableLiveData<List<ModelWrap>>()
    val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getSampleData(pieChart: PieChart){
        val response = repository.getSampleData()
        response.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ModelWrap>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<ModelWrap>>,
                response: Response<List<ModelWrap>>
            ) {
                sampleList.postValue(response.body())
                
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ModelWrap>>, t: Throwable) {
                errorMessage.postValue(t.message)
            }

        })
    }
}
```

**MainViewModelFactory.kt**

```
class MainViewModelFactoryconstructor(private val repository: MainRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return  if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)){
            MainViewModel(this.repository) as T
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Sample ViewModel Not Found")
        }
    }
}
```

**MainRepository.kt**

```
class MainRepository constructor(private val retrofitService: ApiInterface){
    fun getSampleData() = retrofitService.getSampleData()
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var pieChart: PieChart

    lateinit var sampleViewModel: MainViewModel

    private val sampleService = ApiClient.getApiSample()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        pieChart = findViewById(R.id.PieChart)

        sampleViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this, MainViewModelFactory(MainRepository(sampleService))).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        getPieChart(pieChart)

    }

    private fun getPieChart(pieCharts: PieChart) {
        mainViewModel.mainList.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d("TAG sample" , "onCreate PieChart: $it")
Log.d("Tag Samples Response" , response.body().toString())
                    if (it != null) {
                        val sampleEntries: List<PieEntry> = ArrayList()
                        for ((attributes) in it!!) {
                            sampleEntries.toMutableList()
                                .add(PieEntry(attributes.positive, attributes.region))
    
        //........................................................................
    
                            val description = Description()
                            description.text = "Samples Data"
                            pieChart.description = description
                            pieChart.invalidate()
                        }
                    }
        })
        mainViewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, Observer {  })
        mainViewModel.getSampleData(pieCharts)
    }
}
```

*and Lastly, here's some or log message:*

```
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@8b795c0 nm : com.example.diargram ic=null
D/Tag Sample Response: null
D/TAG Sample: onCreate PieChart: null
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"
V/StudioTransport: Agent command stream started.
V/StudioTransport: Transport agent connected to daemon.
```

I would appreciate it if someone can help me :D, Thank you

Comment: can you send a sample of your json response

Comment: The body may be null because of serialization errors in the background. What retrofit does is it returns null and no error message

Comment: @ebs237 here's my json
`[
  {
    "samplesAPI": {
      "FID": 11,
      "region": "seoul",
      "positive": 406205
    }
  },
  {
    "samplesAPI": {
      "FID": 12,
      "region": "hoseong",
      "positive": 277553
    }
  }
  ]`

Comment: @ebs237
anyway, i already get the response, but it won't show in my pie chart, any solution?

Comment: for proper implementation MVVM keep a livedata variable to get the value of response and update the data on the pie chart in the MAIN activity

Comment: @ebs237 I got it, but to do that, I need to call the live data from the viewmodel to mainactivity right? then I can pass the data to pieChart in mainactivity? How to do that?, I decided to go that way like the one I posted above because I'm confused, is there any example that can guide me? Thank you anyway

Comment: @ebs237 I've tried to do exactly as u suggested but still, the pie chart doesn't show anything

Comment: check this out https://learntodroid.com/consuming-a-rest-api-using-retrofit2-with-the-mvvm-pattern-in-android/

Comment: if you are still facing some issues let me know

Comment: @ebs237 I've edited my ViewModel and MainActivity, is there anything I need to fix?

Comment: @ebs237 basically, if using recyclerview or any kind of listview we will create an adapter class, and binding it with the ActivityBinding, but here with PieChart, I just don't know how to bind it with MutableLiveData

Comment: When you are using it export the use a method to return a livedata and in the main activity , observe the datachange if the data is different from null set the piechart description to the requested information in the response

Comment: When you are using it, use a method to return a livedata and in the main activity , observe the data change if the data is different from null set the piechart description to the requested information in the response

Comment: @ebs237 Sorry, I don't understand, do you have any examples?

Comment: @ebs237 based on the code above, and based on my logcat, the sampleEntries does not get any data. the logcat is like : `D/sampleEntriesCovid: []
D/sampleEntriesCovid: []`
but the response of "it" is like :
`D/TAG Samples: onCreate PieChart: [SampleWrap(attributes=Samples(FID=11, positive=31, region=seoul,.... and etc`

Comment: It is possible that you ask another question and upload the code for this to the question so that I can see or better still edit this an upload the code.

Comment: @ebs237 sure here's the new one https://stackoverflow.com/q/67383706/11708862

Comment: can't find the page

Comment: @ebs237 it's okay, I already find the solution
Thank you for your guide anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution for my problem:

1. I type the wrong endpoint inside the interface class and it should be like this:

> interface ApiInterface {
> @GET("sample")
> fun getSampleData(): Call<List> }

1. When it comes to assigning the livedata to the view, based on my JSON I should call ArrayList instead of List
2. List item

**Before :**

> val sampleEntries: List = ArrayList()

**After :**

```
val sampleEntries: ArrayList<PieEntry> = ArrayList()
```